# Check security of random byte generator

Tags: random-number-generator, statistical-test

How can I check if the random number generator library that I am using for my app is cryptographically secure or not?

Comment: Try to look at [these questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-test%2brandom-number-generator?tab=Votes). In a nutshell: first you need to decide if you want a PRNG (deterministic) or a TRNG (result differs from run to run and instance to instance). This changes both functionality and the security goals (sub-classes exist). Then, every method providing meaningful insurance of being cryptographically secure requires examination of the code (source or/and object). External examination of the results produced can only prove insecurity.

Comment: Of course there are (third) parties that you should be able to rely on, the examination of methods is stuff for experts. E.g. the RNG in a HSM likely comes with a FIPS 140-2/3 certification.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes still waiting for that first FIPS 140-3 validation.  It seems to be taking forever.

Comment: @Swashbuckler: perhaps that's a chicken-and-egg problem: about nothing requires FIPS 140-3 yet, thus there's no commercial incentive to pass it, few or no commercial device gets it, thus that requirement would add much cost and is not added. And that would be for little benefit: weaknesses outside an HSM perimeter are exploited way more than HSM weaknesses (discounting tales/accounts of weaknesses intentionally planted, with knowledge or active incentive of US certification authorities. After 56-bit DES keys, downgrade-to-export-DH, Dual_EC_DRBG, PBKDF2 still endorsed... why trust NIST?)

Comment: Personally the algorithms are not even the big problem. Strangely enough, I think the key management routines such as KCV calculation, key derivation, proprietary backup etc. is where (PKCS#11 compatible) HSM's really drop the ball. I mean, we were supposed to perform zero IV CBC encryption of a PKCS#1 encoded private key, so we would leak information about the RSA private exponent *by design* (think about that!). And the KCV of symmetric keys is identical to the first bytes of the output stream of CTR using a zero IV.